# Correct way of testing Pandas dataframe values and modifying them

Tags: python, pandas

I need to modify some values of a Pandas dataframe based on a test, and leave the others values intact. I also need to leave the order of the rows intact.

I have a working code, based on iterating on the dataframe's rows. But it's horrendously slow. Is there a quicker way to get it done?

Here are two examples of this very slow code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.number[index].is_integer():
        df.number[index] = int(df.number[index])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.string[index] == "XXX":
        df.string[index] = df.other_colum[index].split("\")[0] + df.other_colum[index].split("\")[1]
    else:
        df.string[index] = df.other_colum[index].split("\")[1] + df.other_colum[index].split("\")[0]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want to avoid iterating through rows in a pandas dataframe as it is slower than other methods pandas has created for accomplishing the same thing. One way of getting around this is using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). You would redefine the `number` column:

```py
df["number"] = df["number"].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x.is_integer() else x)
```

And (re)define the `string` column:

```py
df["string"] = df["other column"].apply(lambda x: x.split("\\")[0] + x.split("\\")[1] if x == r"XX\X" else x.split("\\")[1] + x.split("\\")[0])
```

Made some assumptions based off of the data you removed from the problem set up -- `.split("\")` is incorrect syntax, and "other column" above necessarily has to have a backslash in it in order for your code (and mine) to work, otherwise `.split("\\")[1]` will return an error.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That's exactly what I needed. I've never been very at ease with the lambda functions, but the 100x or even 1000x speed increase your answer brought clearly justifies learning more about them!